# Find out previously selected row in JTable when pressing JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, row

I want to implement a JButton ("Delete row") to delete the row currently selected in a JTable.

JTable.getSelectedRow() works within the selection listener, but does not work out of it.

When the user presses the "Delete row", how can I figure out which row has been selected?

PD: So far, my idea is to create a variable, automatically updated each time the selection listener is called, and when the user presses the button check the value of this variable. However, it does not look very nice...

Comment: Why do you want to delete the row that was *previously* selected, and not the row that is *currently* selected? The currently (first) selected row is available using `JTable.getSelectedRow()`. If that doesn't work, please provide an SSCCE reproducing the problem.

Comment: When I say "previously", I want to say currently. I mean, the row which has been selected just before pressing the button "Delete"

Comment: and getSelectedRow() returns -1 always

Comment: That's not normal. Please provide an SSCCE reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While going through my ListSelectionListener inner class, I found the next line

```
m_view.getInputsTable().clearSelection();
```

Comment the line, and keep working :D